# How to Resume C# Application After the Windows Restart

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Trying to Install IIS and SQL Server one by one using Winforms... But After Installing the IIS.System Needs to be Restarted,After Restarting It Just again Start installing the Same IIS.

So I Need to Know how to Resume the Application After Restarting..
Does Anyone help me with Nice Example???

Comment: You will need to save your state somewhere and read it later. However, this is way to broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You will also need to write to the RunOnce registry key and add a call to your exe so that it will be executed when the user logs back in.

Comment: @nvoigt I reckon PO asking about how to re-run application automatically when OS booted.

Comment: Because it shows no effort about what answers already exist. See if my answer is useful for you and explore the rest by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Basic outline:  To restart after a boot, there is several ways. You could enter a link to your installer into your autostart directory or use the RunOnce registry key (as suggested by Zhaph - Ben Duguid, see below). When your installer runs again, look if there is already a saved state from a previous install, if yes, load this one.

For saving the state, create classes that contain the state to be restored. Write [Serializable] above each class you want to restore, like so

```
[Serializable]
class InstallationState
{
    // whatever you do
}
```

Then

```
FileStream stream = File.Create(filename);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream,myInstallationState);
stream.Close();
```

to save your state to a file and

```
if (File.Exists(filename)) 
{
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    InstallationState myInstallationState= (InstallationState ) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();

    return result;
}
else return null;
```

to load your state back in from the file after the restart.

After your installation has succeded, don't forget to remove the serialization file (that indicates the installation hasn't finished) and the link to the program in autostart.

Comment: This answers the "how to restore my state", but doesn't answer the "how to restart my application after a restart".

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that trivial?

Comment: I would say so, yes, but that appears to be what is being asked. As Steve Harris noted in his comment, one option would be to write to the RunOnce registry key. A better option though might be to use the Windows Desired State Configuration tools to install IIS and SQL exactly as you need them, which would take care of restarts, etc. for you.